# Execute action after post is saved with all related post_meta records (data)

Tags: post-meta, save-post

I have to execute custom PHP code after new post is saved with all it's meta data.

My question is how to achieve that? Tried with **save_post** action, but it executes before meta records are saved, so I cannot use it in this case.

So, how can I run my custom function after post with all related data is saved in database?

**UPDATED:** I tried to achieve with next code in functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse41912_save_post' );

function wpse41912_save_post() {
// get info about latest added post
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '1', 'post_type' => 'post' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    $myFunc_latest_id = $recent_posts[0]['ID']; // id of the latest post
    $myFunc_post_details = get_post($myFunc_latest_id);
    print_r($myFunc_post_details);

    // how to execute php code when all post meta is added?

}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the post meta saved in the same function?

Comment: Hm, not sure about your question... Please check updated part of my question, part of the function.php file

Answer (score 6):

For **NEW** post type 'post' use `draft_to_publish` action hook:

```
function fpw_post_info( $post ) {
    if ( 'post' == $post->post_type ) {
        // echo '<pre>'; print_r( $post ); echo '<br />';
        // $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID ); print_r( $meta ); echo '</pre>'; die();
        // your custom code goes here...
    }
}
add_action( 'draft_to_publish', 'fpw_post_info', 10, 1 );
```

In your callback function `$post` is your post as `WP_post` object. You'll get post's meta calling `get_post_meta` function.

For **NEW** or **UPDATED** post type 'post' use `publish_post` action hook:

```
function fpw_post_info( $id, $post ) {
    // echo '<pre>'; print_r( $post ); echo '<br />';
    // $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID ); print_r( $meta ); echo '</pre>'; die();
    // your custom code goes here...
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'fpw_post_info', 10, 2 );
```

In this case the callback function takes two parameters!

Comment: Thank you, but nothing happens by using publish_post action hook... I also tried to use added_post_meta hook but it executes after every added post meta - i need the one that executes after last added meta

Comment: What do you mean nothing happens? Did you use the code above without un-commenting first two comments? Show me your code? Do you use it for custom post type or just for 'post'?

Comment: Read updated answer for proper use of `publish_post` action hook.

Comment: Does this work for WooCommerce Products as well?

Comment: A woocommerce product is a custom post type. The above solution works with any post type.

Answer (score 6):

Quite stupid solution, but works:

```
function afterPostUpdated($meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key='', $meta_value=''){
    if($meta_key=='_edit_lock') {
        if($_GET['message']==1) {
            //
            Your code here
            // 
        }
    }
}
add_action('updated_post_meta', 'afterPostUpdated', 10, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use this:

```php
function myFunction($post_id, $post, $update ) {
    // your code here
}

add_action('save_post', 'myFunction');
```

`$update` is a boolean and return false if this is a new post. If it's an update it returns true.

Here is the documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/

Answer (score 1):

The correct and simpler answer is to use the `wp_insert_post` action.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_insert_post/

> An important distinction of wp_insert_post action is that it is fired
> after update_post_meta has been called.

There are 3 parameters available - the $update flag tells you if this is a new or updated post.

```
add_action('wp_insert_post', 'run_after_post_updated', 10, 3);    
function run_after_post_updated($post_ID, $post = null, $update = true) {
   //even though the docs say 3 parameters, it seems sometimes only the postid is passed - so you need defaults on the other 2 parameters
   $meta = get_post_meta( $post_ID ); 
   //  ...
}
```