# call a function when insert and update a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, plugin-development, theme-development, hooks

Here I have custom post type called `products` and it's taxonomy is  `product_categories` . What I need is whenever I add the post in products , I need to call  function1, when I update the post then I need to call function2 . How to do this?

I have searched on google and found this solution:

```
add_action('save_post', 'save_in_filter', 10, 2);
        function save_in_filter($post_id, $post){
          function1();  
        }


 function mynewproduct(){
    myfunction();
}
```

But what happens is when I click on add new post then suddenly the function1() execute , but what i need is   function1 execute after inserting the data  not before inserting the data.

When a post is added to products `(post_type=products)` i need to
 execute `function1()`. When a post is updated in products i need to
 execute `function2();` Why  **post_updated,save_post** function not working properly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**This is the original answer but it is little faulty, look below for the updated**

You can use following approach.

The `my_action_updated_post_meta` is executed after the post insert or update is done:

```
// define the updated_post_meta callback
function my_action_updated_post_meta( $array, $int, $int ) {
    global $post;

    // see your updated post
    print_r($post);

    // make your action here...
    die('after update');
};

// add the action
add_action( 'updated_post_meta', 'my_action_updated_post_meta', 10, 3 );
```

Here's the function's [documentation page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/updated_%28meta_type%29_meta).

**Update**

I have notice that the above response is a little faulty - the `updated_post_meta` action (for post updates) is fired also when opening post for edition in the admin panel (since the `_edit_lock` is set then), even when no real change is made then.

So I changed the approach.

I use a global variable `$my_updated_flag` to know that a "real" change has been made. I set this variable to "1" by `post_updated` action. So if `$my_updated_flag == 1` we know that this is not just a `_edit_lock` change. To differentiate post insert and update action I check the `$post->post_status == 'draft'` since new posts have "draft" status at this stage.

```
$my_updated_flag = 0;

// define the updated_post_meta callback
function action_updated_post_meta( $meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value = '' ) {
    global $post, $my_updated_flag;

    if ($my_updated_flag == 1) {
        if ($post->post_status == 'draft') {
            die('post_inserted');
        } else {
            die('post_updated');
        }
        $my_updated_flag = 0;
    }
};
add_action( 'updated_post_meta', 'action_updated_post_meta', 10, 4 );

function action_post_updated( $array, $int, $int ) {
    global $my_updated_flag;
    $my_updated_flag = 1;
};
add_action( 'post_updated', 'action_post_updated', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: why updated_post_meta ? also please tell how can i check post type is products ?

Comment: As far I understood he needs to execute two functions at different levels. Like execute `function1()` when he added the post and after inserting the post he is needed to execute `function2()`. Isn't it @abilasher ?

Comment: I have updated the answer - check the `$post` object variable - you can get all the post data from it including `post_type`: `$post->post_type`.

Comment: @the_dramatist . yes , when a post is added to products (post_type=products) i need to execute function1(). When a post is updated in products i need to execute function2();

Comment: Right, that's a good point - I forgot. I've checked it again - when the post is added the function is executed for the first time when the `post_status` is still `draft` so you can try to differentiate by this property.

Comment: @Picard it is working . Could you please tell post_updated,save_post function not working properly  ? Also here how can i get the post id ? how can i distinguish post is updated or added ?

Answer (score 1):

have a look at the `post_updated` hook for example..

```
// Hook to all private or public post types updating
add_action( 'post_updated', 'my_function' );    

function my_function( $post_id ){

    $post_status = get_post_status( $post_id );

    switch ( $post_status ) {
        case 'draft':
        case 'auto-draft':
        case 'pending':
        case 'inherit':
        case 'trash':
            return;

        case 'future':
        case 'publish':
        case 'private':
            // continue

    }

   'do something; 
}
```

Comment: it is not working friend

Answer (score 0):

You can check these links bellow:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/192323/68186

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post